# C# javascript click button by tag and attribute

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I'm having some trouble getting my program to click a button:

```
 <a class="button_recruit" style="letter-spacing: -1px" href="/myrecruitlink" data-executing="0">Recruit</a>
```

That is the button I'm trying to click but when I add the code for it it does nothing, I'm new to C# and trying to learn this. So if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong here I would very much appreciate it.

Here is the program code:

```
 namespace clean_test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\AppEvents\\Schemes\\Apps\\Explorer\\Navigating\\.Current", "", "NULL");
        web.Navigate("http://www.mywebsite.com");
    }

    private void recruit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElementCollection elems = web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
        foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
        {
            String value = elem.GetAttribute("value");
            if (value != null && value.Length != 0 && value.Equals("Recruit"))
            {
                recruit.PerformClick();
            }
        }
    }


  }
}
```

Comment: Check my solution and tell me if it is working !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think other guys don't understand your question. You need this line:

```
private void recruit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     HtmlElementCollection elems = web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
     foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
     {
         String value = elem.GetAttribute("value");

         //you can use elem.InnerText.Equals("Recruit") too, if value == null.
         if (value != null && value.Length != 0 && value.Equals("Recruit"))
         {
             elem.InvokeMember("click");
         }
     }
 }
```

Hope I help you !

Comment: You understood what I meant, but still the same results, It doesn't show any errors but also still wont click the recruit button. I'm stumped

Comment: @David use debug and tell me did you go in the if statement ? If you doesn't enter in the if try with my check. if(elem.InnerText.Equals("Recruit"), because it is possible value to be null !

Comment: Also with elem.InnerText.Equals("Recruit") it does show an error, Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'

Comment: @David are sure you write it correctly, try this elem.InnerText == "Recruit".

Comment: Correction, I made a mistake typing it if(elem.InnerText.Equals("Recruit") Solved my problem Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go client side ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function NewFunction(){
//do something here
}
</script>
```

and change to button with `OnClientClick` attribute

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="button_recruit" style="letter-spacing: -1px"  OnClientClick="recruit_Click"  />
```

Or add `onclick` to the existing element you have to fire javascript method.

```
 <a class="button_recruit" style="letter-spacing: -1px" href="/myrecruitlink" data-executing="0" onclick=""NewFunction();">Recruit</a>
```

Comment: I think this question is not about ASP.NET or web development.